# Printing an object string value located on JSON file using JAVA Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I will keep it simple - trying to print the username ('user') value of this JSON file with JACKSON:

```
{
"creds" : {
          "user": "Y9CJG1756",
          "pass": "12222#$1"
 },
"env": {
        "qa": {
               "url": "https://www.walla.com/"
         }
  }
}
```

I'm running this function but could only find a way to print the entire string of the object 'creds' instead of just the user name.

```
public static void isJsonStringWorks(String filePath) {
    try {
        JsonNode objectValue;

        byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
        objectValue = rootNode.get("creds");
        System.out.println("object is: " + objectValue + " ,\n" + rootNode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not read the JSON file");
    }

}
```

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: did you try with objectValue.get('user').textValue() ?

Comment: What value  System.out.println("object is: " + objectValue + " ,\n" + rootNode); is printing ?

Comment: System.out.println("object is: " + objectValue.get("user") + " ,\n" + rootNode);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
objectValue = rootNode.get("creds").get("user").asText()
```

Also you shall consider the following options:

- Introduce Java representation of your data model and read source JSON string as Java object (using `objectMapper.readValue(...)` method). After that it will be possible to access values like usual Java beans (`root.getCreds().getUser()`)
- Using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to access "deep" values inside JSON to simplify JSON values lookup. For example creds/user value could be obtained like:

  ```
  String json = "...";
  Object document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json);
  String value = JsonPath.read(document, "$.creds.user")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you are on right route.
You can call `objectValue.get('user')`